# War Thunder: bonus per aircraft.

Tags: war-thunder

Does the 40+40 mean credits or exp boost?

I'm confused as it doesn't clearly state what it means (sorry I'm new to the game).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reward bonus is applied to both credit and experience gain.

In your case, it means there'll be an 80% (40% + 40%) increase to your base credit and experience gain, garnered at the end of each battle. The other 40% (the base reward bonus is on the left, aka 40%) comes from the aircraft in question being a premium one, which doubles the base reward bonus.